# Can someone help me with this limits problem

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin \{\sqrt{x}\}}{\{\sqrt{x}\}}$$

Where $\{x\}$ is the decimal part of $x$.

How do I go about solving this problem? Thank you

Comment: Decimal part doesn't matter, then just use the limit for $sin(x)/x$.

Comment: What is the relevance of the decimal part when the limit is towards $0$?

Comment: It's a scan, isn't it?  OP probably doesn't have much of a choice in how it was formulated.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Note that for $x \in (0,1)$, we have $\{\sqrt{x}\} = \sqrt{x}$.